# Blackberry advertising service in webworks

Tags: html, blackberry

i am using the blackberry advertising service in my webworks app. banner is displaying. its not doing anything if i click on the banner. following is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.blackberry.com/app_includes/asdk/adBanner.js"></script>

<center> <div id='bannerDiv'></div> </center>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var bannerObj = new blackberry.advertising.Banner(31848, "bannerDiv" , {
 "bannerTransitions" : true,
 "mmaSize" : "auto",
 "metadata" : { "age" : "12", "activity" :
 "low" },
 "refreshRate" : 90000,
 "focusBorderColor" : "blue",
 "focusBorderWidth" : "1px",
 "placeholder" : "http://www.bbmanimated.com/bbmapp2/images/banner.png"
 });
</script>
```

what shall i do ? please help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the banner, but you are not associating any functions to it.  You need to do some thing like "onClick()" and provide the instructions to it.

I hope that helps.

Thanks

Naveen M